# Automatic table of content (TOC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, tableofcontents

I'm building a website from markdown documents. I want to add a table of content so I need to automatically convert this HTML source (automatically rendered from markdown):

src:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>Article title</h1>
  <h2>example header 1</h2>
  <h2>example header 2</h2>
  <h2>example header 3</h2>
  <h3>example sub-header 1</h3>
  <h3>example sub-header 2</h3>
</div>
```

dest:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1 id="article-title">Article title</h1>
  <h2 id="example-header-1">example header 1</h2>
  <h2 id="example-header-2">example header 2</h2>
  <h2 id="example-header-3">example header 3</h2>
  <h3 id="example-sub-header-1">example sub-header 1</h3>
  <h3 id="example-sub-header-2">example sub-header 2</h3>
</div>
<div id="toc">
  <p>Article title</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#example-header-1">example header 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-header-2">example header 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#example-header-3">example header 3</a></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#example-sub-header-1">example sub-header 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-sub-header-2">example sub-header 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </li><a href="#content">Back to top</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've done part of the work With jQuery, but I'm a noob with this and I can't continue:

```
// Append "Back to top" button to TOC element
$("#toc ul").append(
  "<p>" + $('#doc h1:first').text() + "</p>"
);

// automatic table of content generation
$("#doc h2").each(function() {
  // Add automatic ID for each heading element
  var header = $(this).text();
  var anchor = header
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')
    .replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
  $(this).attr("id", anchor);
  // Create TOC
  $("#toc ul").append(
    "<li><a href='#" + anchor + "'>" + header + "</a></li>"
  );
});

// Append "Back to top" button to TOC element
$("#toc ul").append(
  "<li><a href='#top'>Back to top</a></li>"
);
```

Somebody can help me to finish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm a noob with this and I can't continue"? What is the question? Where is the problem that you're having?

Comment: With that I'm be able to create `li` tags inside the `#toc` list with `<h2>` tags. But I also want to create `<ul><li></li></ul>` tags for `<h3>`, `<h4>`, etc as I've explained in the question.